# How do you change image on mouse hold then execute event upon release?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pretty straightforward question.

Im studying web design and I want to make buttons out of images wherein the images change appearance upon mouse hover(ive already figured that part out) and then when clicked will change their appearance for the duration that the click is held and the upon release, will execute the desired event like moving to another page.

Been on this for 2 hours now and I was wondering if you could help.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<script>

function changeImage()
{
element = document.getElementById('homeImage');
if (element.src.match("Home2"))
  {
    element.src = "Home.png";
  }
else
  {
    element.src = "Home2.png";
  }
}
function Execute()
{
element = document.getElementById('homeImage');
element.src = "Home3.png";
}
</script>
```

Comment: mouse events would probably be your best bet as shown below by Carlos and Shoaib.

Comment: @SandyBites please mark the answer if that helped you to help others.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events.

```
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    // Do stuff when the mouse is held down on `element`
});
element.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    // Do stuff when the mouse is released.
});
```

Feel free to [read up on events here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `onmouseup` and `onmousedown` events:

```
element.onmouseup=function(){ //this will be executed whenever the click is released..
SomeJavaScriptCode};

element.onmousedown=function(){ //This will be executed on click..
SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var start;
var end;
var time;
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    start = d.getTime();

});
element.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    end = d.getTime();
    time = end-start;
    //do something with time

});
```

Comment: Hi, @Eric. Although the time calculation is a nice addition, I am unable to see where the question asked for that. Did I miss something?

Comment: " then when clicked will change their appearance for the duration that the click "

Comment: I think that means that the appearance will remain changed as long as the image is "clicked" (i.e., the mouse is held down). Perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: What i understand is the change is relative to the amount of time the mouse is down, maybe OP can clarify ?

Comment: NP Chris, I didn't suspect you haha you sound like a nice dude

Answer (score 0):

You can use .mousedown* and .mouseup from jQuery so you change image when the mouse is clicked on your element and change again when the mouse is released.

Comment: @SandyBites is obviously starting with very simple code and he/she is only starting to get involved with Web development and JavaScript programming. Introducing jQuery into the scene seems like extra complexity.

Comment: @Chris Why you do this ? IF somebody is learning something then he/she should be shown all the possible directions, atleast carlos didnt misguided him!

Comment: @ShoaibRaza This isn't a contest. I was merely expressing an opinion with the comment. Saying "at least Carlos didn't misguide him/her" doesn't really help anyone. If Carlos was misguiding, I would've simply downvoted Carlos' answer. If it was not an answer, I would've flagged it. This is how a collaborative community works.